# Can I send raw TCP data directly from Mikrotik using script?

Tags: mikrotik

I want to control some [network relay](https://youtu.be/0Gnxaf7Dlt0) that accepts commands from PuTTY in raw mode.

Is it possible to do this with Mikrotik router? As far I know Mikrotik routers have ssh and telnet client server and client, but what if I want to send raw data?

Comment: It might have netcat or `nc` that can be used to send raw data.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen It does not have netcat and it looks like it cannot be installed (https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=43689). Linux virtual machine can be installed (and netcat "inside"), but my device probably has not enough memory (64MB and it uses about 40MB all the time).

Comment: You can try cross-compiling netcat with statically linked libraries and copy the binary over to the router and use it. That takes some effort though.